# pprvent script matching url

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to stop a script from firing on certain pages. IS there a way I could do that by reading strings from urls and prvent the function from loading in those specific pages. Is it really possible? I want to run the script in all the otehr pages and the script is included at a template level

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't do it via the page URLs.  Instead, do something like adding a class to the `<html>` tag for the pages where the script should (or shouldn't) run, and have it check that before doing anything.

So:

```
<html class='dont-run-script'>
```

and then the script can be predicated on that like this:

```
if (!$('body').is('.dont-run-script *')) {
  // all the code
}
```

(Obviously the code shouldn't run before the body is loaded, so it should be imported at the end or else the code should be in a "ready" or "load" handler.)

Comment: I can just put a div in the dom correct? Does it have to be the <html> tag?

Comment: @Soum Sure you can use any scheme like that; it doesn't have to be the `<html>` tag.